# Having errors with Scribe implementing oauth with facebook

Tags: java, spring-boot, scribe, restfb

Hello guys i'm trying to use scribe for an oauth service to get a token from facebook and will try to pass the token to restfb to get some data from facebook. But for now having trouble with scribe. I was able to build with gradle but when i tried running the program encountered errors. Error is attached below and states `No qualifying bean of type [org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService found for dependency`.

HomeController:

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public class HomeController {

     private static final String STATE = "state";
     private String client_id = "*********";
     private String app_secret = "************";
     private String url = "http://localhost:8080/";
     private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
     private OAuthService oAuthService;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(OAuthService oAuthService) {
    oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
    }

    private OAuthService buildOAuthService(String client_id, String app_secret){
     return new ServiceBuilder()
            .apiKey(client_id)
            .apiSecret(app_secret)
            .callback(url+"/auth/facebook/callback")
            .provider(FacebookApi.class)
            .build();
       }

     @RequestMapping(value="/auth/facebook", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public RedirectView startAuthentication(HttpSession httpSession) throws OAuthException {
            String state = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
             httpSession.setAttribute(STATE, state);
             String authorizationUrl = oAuthService.getAuthorizationUrl(Token.empty())
            +"&"+STATE+"="+state;
      return new RedirectView(authorizationUrl);
     }

         @RequestMapping(value="/auth/facebook/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public RedirectView callback(@RequestParam("code")String code, @RequestParam(STATE)String state, HttpSession httpsession) throws IOException
        {
              String stateFromSession = (String)httpsession.getAttribute(STATE);
             if(!state.equals(stateFromSession)) {
                  return new RedirectView("/login");
                }

       Token accessToken = getAccessToken(code);
       return new RedirectView("/loggedin");
           }

         private Token getAccessToken(String code) {
               Verifier verify = new Verifier(code);
             return oAuthService.getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verify);
           }
 }
```

Error:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [/home/emy/IdeaProjects/facebookArchiver/build/classes/main/edu/sjsu/cmpe273/facebookarchiver/HomeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at edu.sjsu.cmpe273.facebookarchiver.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 18 common frames omitted

2015-04-26 18:15:54.905  INFO 7334 --- [           main]       o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-04-26 18:15:54.910  INFO 7334 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/emy/IdeaProjects/facebookArchiver/src/main/resources/, file:/home/emy/IdeaProjects/facebookArchiver/build/classes/main/, file:/home/emy/IdeaProjects/facebookArchiver/build/resources/main/, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook/2.0.0.RELEASE/b0c635786ede56d002b5c27f213eed4352bbb059/spring-social-facebook-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.2.3.RELEASE/bebade6f3d65466c134b876f9bf065868e8ff6a7/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.3.RELEASE/d4a2ea5c2dfa465054d9b2675ff7794d8d97f311/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scribe/scribe/1.3.5/a3b3deded9d241d9f2c8aa9c9bcd90ad29e2581e/scribe-1.3.5.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.social/spring-social-config/1.1.0.RELEASE/31232c1fa1ac9bacaaceed0835245f2f3c4f0982/spring-social-config-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.4.5/b400d47efaf8ab612c03b904ae5bf26c6706ade6/jackson-annotations-2.4.5.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.4.5/c69c0cb613128c69d84a6a0304ddb9fce82e8242/jackson-databind-2.4.5.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.5/6fb96728ee26edb19fe329d94f3bd4df1a97652a/jackson-core-2.4.5.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.social/spring-social-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/720ab4059320908a0f101e0567919319bcfe2746/spring-social-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.3.RELEASE/a50eea39bce85f09db0fc43d80e86aa767e8cc24/spring-boot-starter-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.1.6.RELEASE/e2f486124d5dea2d91a9c2ea7d4456bc343ca2cc/spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/e5677e7daedfd05e001945abf4295305ac23826b/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.2.7/96a7509eb8cf8bdb5a9b82b93de9b76ecb915d1b/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.7.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.3.RELEASE/32de443f4e43ceee62c3e1e855fee076fec546b3/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/334d46a93cf095160ce06d8382594b904933c808/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.1.6.RELEASE/960101b25d0ec6f45d550bf92c00de8c6a584e6a/spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.6.RELEASE/e1ee19a5359f214d65cc18972df8aba17ce1e423/spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.social/spring-social-web/1.1.0.RELEASE/393d7fd2e0d87dbc9c96ae2d6c432ea704c94a6d/spring-social-web-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.2.3.RELEASE/2601c81786dd8d88fd7e53af1a3950ef45fd5507/spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.3.RELEASE/11175f217ac34bdacd6282cd44310f211121e270/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.3.RELEASE/43093c137ea9c6d26ca6341e17295c0a6c506dfb/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/c2df91929ed06a25001939929bff5120e0ea3fd4/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/a730d892f3c57ba3d24af2ca657b42d81398a85a/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.20/5810725255089f4d0b7ab19ac70b8c4a9cd8d4a3/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.20/8050b326d0ee31ba91b06e420b57efe77a6f0516/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.20.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.20/234ee053b3dbd4bca2fc221a99d4f7d292d33e0b/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.20.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.20/b4914491d1baa90958e5c951bec7140e65874f3/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/64499e907f19e5e1b3fdc02f81440c1832fe3545/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/434efef28c81162b17c540e634cffa3bd9b09b4c/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.1.6.RELEASE/ce2d409d470948f11fad41ffdf37dcff4d28cd7c/spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/15f0b22bf89ed468badbc4eec759af2b916d33e4/spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.1.6.RELEASE/8bf70887c2c883a6f6e552dbe46eec35c07adf6a/spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.11/180246b7809ffae6293eea3d34e668ee948f0dc8/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.11/87a1d59c837c57396bc20f433ee24ad3a59c7812/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.11.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.11/4f51599470151c7b8ebec1d36767138f7fb7d427/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.11.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/d90276fff414f06cb375f2057f6778cd63c6082f/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.1.6.RELEASE/686c13ba57d9423dede9c5d580dcadc5c67a2761/spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.3/e3c02049f2dbbc764681b40094ecf0dcbc99b157/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686/commons-logging-1.2.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/37e1aebfde7eb7baebc9ad4f85116ef9009c5fc5/ognl-3.0.8.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA/315891b371395271977af518d4db5cee1a0bc9bf/javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/ab0db4fe0a6fa89fb8da2a40008a4e63a7f3f5b9/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/emy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.11/7eaaaf2238f324e2b02dbd4d6ced6778b99328/slf4j-api-1.7.11.jar]
2015-04-26 18:15:54.915  INFO 7334 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
public HomeController(OAuthService oAuthService) {
     oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
}
```

With this constructor you are asking the Spring container to inject a `OAuthService` but you never use it instead you build your own `OAuthService` using `buildOAuthService` method. So remove the `@Autowired` from the above code to get rid of the exception you are getting.

```
public HomeController() {
     oAuthService = buildOAuthService(client_id, app_secret);
}
```